# How do I know which force to use in moments calculation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, statics, moment

I'm working on some Statics problem, with the method of joints, etc and for all of them, we use sum of moments = 0. However, I'm very confused about which forces I should use to find the sum of moments and which forces shouldn't be used.

Can someone give me some tips/tricks to this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I think you've probably got a very good conceptual question, but I have no idea what you are talking about. It would be very helpful to include some links to "method of joints" or "sum of moments", or just show us a simple example and point out where exactly you are confused.

Comment: I totally agree with ACuriousMind, but maybe you can answer your own question with some intuition - pick one of the situations you are confused by and consider it as a 'real life situation', rather than an abstract problem. Which forces would you expect to cause movement? These forces need to be accounted for when finding the static condition.

Comment: I'm testing this out on a problem that I found: http://i.imgur.com/JQq35mR.jpg. My question is that if I want to find the moment at point A, which forces should I use? Should I use the force in CE from the wall, etc? I'm just confused on as to which forces I need to use.

Comment: You have to take into account all forces, except the ones which pass through the point about which you want the sum of moments to be zero

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the sum of moments, you have to take **all the external forces ** into account. The summation of moments has no preference for a certain force, allowing it to be in the equation. All forces are in the summation, only their resulting moment can be zero.
If we look at the following example, assuming that all the spacings, e.g. $AB,BC,BE,FC,CD$ are equal to  $l$:

[image]

If we take the sum of moments around $A$ with clockwise positive, we get

$$\Sigma M_A=(AA) \cdot R_1 - (AB)\cdot P_1-(AB+BC)\cdot P_2+(AB+BC+CD)\cdot R_2 =0  $$

As you can see, all the forces are included in the sum of the moments. However, if we start filling in the appropriate lengths we get:

$$\Sigma M_A=(0l) \cdot R_1 - (l)\cdot P_1-(2l)\cdot P_2+(3l)\cdot R_2 =0$$

This is because the distance $AA$ is equal to zero, making the moment contribution equal to zero. For a moment, you need a distance and a force. If either is $0$, the moment is zero.
It can be shown that every force that goes through the point of consideration ($A$ in this case), has a moment contribution of zero.
Take for example $P_1=P_2=F $(downward) , this maken $R_1$ and $R_2$ also equal to $F$ (upward).
If we then make a cut around $A$, right through the middle of $AE$ and $AB$ we get:

[image]

Since all distances are equal ($AB=AE$), the angle is $45\deg$.
Using this angle, we can decompose $F_{ae}$ into $F_{ae_x}$ and  $F_{ae_y}$
The sum of moments around $A$ gives:
$$\Sigma M_A=(0l) \cdot R_1 + F_{ae_y} \cdot \Delta x_{ae} - F_{ae_x} \cdot \Delta y_{ae} + F_{ab} \cdot \Delta y_{ab}=0$$

Noting that $\Delta y_{ab}=0$, we get
$$\Sigma M_A= F_{ae_y} \cdot \Delta x_{ae} - F_{ae_x} \cdot \Delta y_{ae} =0$$

If we rewrite the values of $F_{ae_y}$ and $F_{ae_x}$ in terms of $F$

$$\Sigma M_A= F_{ae} \sin(45) \cdot \Delta x_{ae} - F_{ae_x} \cos(45) \cdot \Delta y_{ae} =0$$

or

$$\Sigma M_A= F_{ae} \left[ \sin(45) \cdot \Delta x_{ae} -  \cos(45) \cdot \Delta y_{ae} \right] =0$$

If we look at this formula, we see that the total moment contribution of $F_{ae}$, thus the horizontal component and the vertical component added, add to $0$. This means $F_{ae}$ does not have a moment on $A$. We can generalize this result as

**If a force passes through the point of consideration, the moment
 contribution is $0$**

Just like @Pranav Hosangadi said.

This example shows this as, all three forces go through point $A$, therefore all their contribtions are $0$, adding up to $0$.

This can be a very useful shortcut. If for example you have a structure which is loaded by 30 forces, of which 28 go through the same point, you can sum the moments around this point, and neglect the moment contribution of the 28 forces, grealy simplifying the calculation. You can also take any other point, and the results will be the same, it's just more math to do.